# Dealing with a nonlinear oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

> Given the following differential equation
>
> $$\ddot x + (x^2+\dot x^2-1) \dot x + x = 0$$
>
> find the polar equations of motion in state space.

This is for my classical mechanics course, but it seems more mathematics than physics, which is why I am asking this here. I am totally lost. I thought about using a substitution $y = \dot x$, which results in

$$\dot y = (1-x^2)y-y^3$$

which doesn't seem oscillatory.  I also see that it is very similar in form to the van der Pol oscillator, but there are additional terms.  So I am just looking for a hint on how to go about this.  Thanks.

Comment: Write the equations as a first order ODE in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and see it that helps.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: $\dot y = (1-x^2)y-y^3-\color{red}{x}$

Comment: You already have.  Now sketch the state-space, which is the $x-y$ plane.  For a dozen or so points $(x,y)$, calculate $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$.  Then draw an arrow at the point $(x,y)$, in the direction $(\dot{x},\dot{y})$.  You will build up a picture of how the function changes in time.  For example, in the upper half-plane, $y>0$, so $\dot{x}>0$, so $x$ is increasing, and flow is to the right.  In the lower half-plane, it is to the left.

Comment: If you let $y =\dot{x}$, then $\dot{y} = \ddot{x}$. So, you get $\dot{y} = -\left(  (x^2+y^2-1)y +x \right)$, $\dot{x} = y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question, interesting problem, one of my favorites, wish I could upvote the question more than once!

So the equation of interest is

$\ddot x+(x^2+\dot x^2-1)\dot x + x=0. \tag{1}$

Well, we want a polar expression for (1).  So we begin by making the two-dimensional, planar aspects of (1) obvious, since polars can't really be applied in any nice way to an equation on the line; this transformation is affected by introducing a new variable $y$, and setting $y = \dot x$, so:

$\dot x = y, \tag{2}$

then substituting $y$ from (2) into (1) we obtain

$\dot y = - (x^2 + y^2 - 1)y - x. \tag{3}$

Taken together, (2) and (3) form a planar system, often called the phase representation of the equation (1); a point in the $x$-$y$ plane now may be interpreted as a complete state of (1), since it contains all the information needed to determine the ensuing trajectory uniquely, i.e., position and velocity.  We cast (2), (3) in polar form by setting

$x = r \cos \theta, \tag{4}$

$y = r \sin \theta, \tag{5}$

from which readily follows

$\dot x = \dot r \cos \theta -r \dot \theta \sin \theta, \tag{6}$

$\dot y =\dot r \sin \theta + r\dot \theta \cos \theta. \tag{7}$

We now insert (4)-(7) into (2), (3) and, as the old song says, "boil that cabbage down", so to speak, by cooking things on the stove of algebraic manipulation:

$\dot r \cos \theta -r \dot \theta \sin \theta = r\sin \theta, \tag{8}$

$\dot r \sin \theta + r\dot \theta \cos \theta = - (r^2 \cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta - 1) r \sin \theta - r \cos \theta;\tag{9}$

now, as Bob Marley sang, we *Stir It Up*; so, pretty baby, we re-write (8), (9) a little bit.  Notice that, in terms of the vector $(\dot r, \dot \theta)^T$ the combined
lefts of these two equations can be written in matrix-vector form, whence we arrive at

$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & - r\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \dot r \\ \dot \theta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r \sin \theta \\ -(r^2 - 1)r \sin \theta -r \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}.  \tag{10}$

Now as long as $r \ne 0$, the matrix on the left-hand side of (10) is nonsingular; indeed its determinant is $r$:

$\det \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & - r\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} = r(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) = r; \tag{11}$

thus it may be simply inverted; indeed, a standard calculation yields

$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & - r\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{r} \begin{bmatrix} r\cos \theta &  r\sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}; \tag{12}$

keep stirring, keep stirring, keep boiling:  multiply (10) by (12) and grind; we obtain

$\begin{pmatrix} \dot r \\ \dot \theta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -r(r^2 - 1) \sin^2 \theta \\ -(r^2 -1)(\cos \theta)(\sin \theta) -1 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{13}$

the equation (1) in polar form may thus be written out in non-vector form as

$\dot r = -r(r^2 - 1) \sin^2 \theta, \tag{14}$

$\dot \theta = -(r^2 -1)(\cos \theta)(\sin \theta) -1 = -\frac{1}{2}(r^2 -1)\sin 2 \theta -1. \tag{15}$

There! Cabbage ready!  It is worth noting that (14) implies, as long as $\sin^2 \theta \ne 0$, $r$ increases as long as $0 < r < 1$ and decreases when $r > 1$; when $r = 1$ we have

$\dot r = 0, \tag{16}$

and

$\dot \theta = -1; \tag{17}$

the circle $r = 1$ is apparently a stable, closed, periodic orbit of period $2\pi$, rotating in the clockwise direction.  In the event $\sin^2 \theta = 0$, we have that $\theta = m\pi$ for some integer $m$; then $\sin 2\theta = 0$ as well, so that from (15) $\dot \theta = -1$; the condition $\dot r = 0$ is thus seen to be an "instantaneous" phenomenon; $r$ will continue to increase/decrease along a trajectory except at these particular values of $\theta$, with $r \to 1$.  Properties of solutions near points where $\dot \theta = 0$ may be investigated using (15); I leave such questions to my readers.  Other interesting features of the flow may be derived from examination of (15), (16); but my night job beckons, and so I must bid you all *adieu*.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

To complement Robert Lewis's answer, here is a [Grapher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) plot of the vector field:

[image]

Indeed, it looks as though the **unit circle** is a *stable* [limit cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle).

Visual inspection of the plot above suggests that the origin is *unstable*. The Jacobian at the origin has complex eigenvalues with positive real parts. Hence, indeed, the origin is an **unstable focus**.

Making $\dot y = 0$, we obtain the implicitly-defined curve $x - (1-x^2-y^2) y = 0$, which is plotted below:

[image]

This [algebraic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve) partitions the phase plane into two regions. In one of these regions the "arrows" point upwards, while in the other region the "arrows" point downwards.